# Dual-boot (Ubuntu 20.04 / Ubuntu 20.04): missing kernel modules on second partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel

I'm having troubles making a manually made dual boot setup work.
**Context: **
I'm working on a Raspberry Pi 4B Ubuntu 20.04 Device with Azure IoT Edge, with Azure Device Update enabled. To make Azure Device Update work, I need to split the disk into many partitions: boot, root FS 1, root FS 2, and a persistent data partition. My automatic process of splitting the disk at first boot works, I can boot on both partition by selecting the other partition in cmdline.txt file (example: root=/dev/mmcblk0p3 ).

The process of creating the partitions is as followed:

```
- Create an image with 4 small sized partitions
- Calculate free space at first boot
- Generate a partition table and use sfdisk to move and resize everything
```

Then to extract the partition for the SWUpdate file:

```
- Download and Decompressing the image
- Generate loop device
- Clone main root fs partition to gzip with dd
```

**Device Update:**
To create an update image, I use the same image than the one on the disk, extract the first root FS partition, and create the SWU file. Then it uses SWUpdate software to update the inactive root FS partition.

**Problem:**
After the update, I can boot on the updated partition, but I have few kernel modules missing. Like ethernet works great but not Wi-Fi. Docker cannot start because br_netfilters and iptables modules are missing too. The first error that pops in dmesg in that autofs4 module is not found.
At first boot on the main root FS partition, everything works fine.
Even when I manually boot on the second partition before any update, it works. But when I update the second partition, and boot on it, few kernel modules seems to be missing. This is weird because it's supposed to be an exact copy of the main partition (see the process of creating the update file). How can files be missing?

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd083]
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-1083-raspi (buildd@bos02-arm64-066) (gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)) #94-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 3 10:06:55 UTC 2023 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-1083.94-raspi 5.4.231)
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1
[    0.000000] efi: Getting EFI parameters from FDT:
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x000000002c000000, size 64 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 1012736
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 3792 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 242688 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.000000]   DMA32 zone: 12032 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   DMA32 zone: 770048 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 32 pages/cpu s92504 r8192 d30376 u131072
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s92504 r8192 d30376 u131072 alloc=32*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3
[    0.000000] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU0
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: EL2 vector hardening
[    0.000000] CPU features: kernel page table isolation forced ON by KASLR
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Kernel page table isolation (KPTI)
[    0.000000] ARM_SMCCC_ARCH_WORKAROUND_1 missing from firmware
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Spectre-BHB
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: ARM erratum 1742098
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 996912
[    0.000000] Kernel command line:  coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1920 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=1080 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=DC:A6:32:53:EA:03 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  elevator=deadline net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc quiet splash quiet splash
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x37400000-0x3b400000] (64MB)
[    0.000000] Memory: 3782900K/4050944K available (13820K kernel code, 1280K rwdata, 4328K rodata, 4096K init, 1079K bss, 202508K reserved, 65536K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 39471 entries in 155 pages
[    0.000000] rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.000000] GIC: Using split EOI/Deactivate mode
[    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 54.00MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0xc743ce346, max_idle_ns: 440795203123 ns
[    0.000006] sched_clock: 56 bits at 54MHz, resolution 18ns, wraps every 4398046511102ns
[    0.000246] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.000272] printk: console [tty1] enabled
[    0.000321] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 108.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=216000)
[    0.000338] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.000772] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.000841] Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.000981] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[    0.001298] Mount-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.001350] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.001479] *** VALIDATE tmpfs ***
[    0.002273] *** VALIDATE proc ***
[    0.002771] cgroup: Disabling memory control group subsystem
[    0.002949] *** VALIDATE cgroup1 ***
[    0.002960] *** VALIDATE cgroup2 ***
[    0.004523] ASID allocator initialised with 32768 entries
[    0.004722] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.006913] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.007875] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.009046] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU1
[    0.009103] CPU1: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000001 [0x410fd083]
[    0.010283] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU2
[    0.010322] CPU2: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000002 [0x410fd083]
[    0.011458] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU3
[    0.011496] CPU3: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000003 [0x410fd083]
[    0.011647] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.011657] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated.
[    0.011668] CPU features: detected: 32-bit EL0 Support
[    0.011679] CPU features: detected: CRC32 instructions
[    0.019582] CPU features: emulated: Privileged Access Never (PAN) using TTBR0_EL1 switching
[    0.019592] CPU: All CPU(s) started at EL2
[    0.019640] alternatives: patching kernel code
[    0.021816] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.033226] Enabled cp15_barrier support
[    0.033253] Enabled setend support
[    0.033720] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.033743] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.035841] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.036607] DMI not present or invalid.
[    0.037655] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.040269] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic allocations
[    0.040289] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.040587] audit: type=2000 audit(0.040:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.041203] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.041245] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.041727] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.042138] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.045235] bcm2835-mbox fe00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.056170] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2021-11-18 16:16, variant start
[    0.060177] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is d9b293558b4cef6aabedcc53c178e7604de90788
[    0.094049] HugeTLB registered 1.00 GiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.094064] HugeTLB registered 32.0 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.094074] HugeTLB registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.094083] HugeTLB registered 64.0 KiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.105606] bcm2835-dma fe007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager, dmachans=0x1
[    0.108877] iommu: Default domain type: Translated
[    0.110448] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.110797] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.111053] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.111098] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.111148] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.111559] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.111568] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.111586] PTP clock support registered
[    0.111883] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    0.113613] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.113623] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.113631] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4 CALIPSO
[    0.113701] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.114717] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.221416] *** VALIDATE bpf ***
[    0.221800] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.221913] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.222064] *** VALIDATE ramfs ***
[    0.222108] *** VALIDATE hugetlbfs ***
[    0.222982] AppArmor: AppArmor Filesystem Enabled
[    0.223466] simple-framebuffer 3e3cf000.framebuffer: framebuffer at 0x3e3cf000, 0x7e9000 bytes, mapped to 0x(____ptrval____)
[    0.223480] simple-framebuffer 3e3cf000.framebuffer: format=a8r8g8b8, mode=1920x1080x32, linelength=7680
[    0.224129] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    0.235343] simple-framebuffer 3e3cf000.framebuffer: fb0: simplefb registered!
[    0.246046] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'fair_share'
[    0.246053] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'bang_bang'
[    0.246063] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.246071] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'user_space'
[    0.246079] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'power_allocator'
[    0.246765] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.247315] IP idents hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.250197] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 2048 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    0.250248] TCP established hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.250427] TCP bind hash table entries: 32768 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.251011] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 32768 bind 32768)
[    0.251256] UDP hash table entries: 2048 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.251307] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 2048 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.251603] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.251634] NET: Registered protocol family 44
[    0.251651] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    0.251921] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    0.949577] Freeing initrd memory: 29732K
[    0.951320] hw perfevents: enabled with armv8_cortex_a72 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.951523] kvm [1]: IPA Size Limit: 44 bits
[    0.952432] kvm [1]: vgic interrupt IRQ1
[    0.952662] kvm [1]: Hyp mode initialized successfully
[    0.955113] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    0.955178] Key type blacklist registered
[    0.955457] workingset: timestamp_bits=46 max_order=20 bucket_order=0
[    0.963285] zbud: loaded
[    0.965862] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    0.967157] fuse: init (API version 7.31)
[    0.967304] *** VALIDATE fuse ***
[    0.967317] *** VALIDATE fuse ***
[    0.991678] Key type asymmetric registered
[    0.991688] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    0.991734] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 242)
[    0.991908] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    0.996469] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: host bridge /scb/pcie@7d500000 ranges:
[    0.996489] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   No bus range found for /scb/pcie@7d500000, using [bus 00-ff]
[    0.996540] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:      MEM 0x0600000000..0x0603ffffff -> 0x00f8000000
[    0.996590] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   IB MEM 0x0000000000..0x00bfffffff -> 0x0400000000
[    1.044817] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: link up, 5.0 GT/s PCIe x1 (SSC)
[    1.045112] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    1.045126] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
[    1.045142] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x600000000-0x603ffffff] (bus address [0xf8000000-0xfbffffff])
[    1.045187] pci 0000:00:00.0: [14e4:2711] type 01 class 0x060400
[    1.045388] pci 0000:00:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[    1.049153] pci 0000:01:00.0: [1106:3483] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    1.049281] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
[    1.049626] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3cold
[    1.053395] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 14: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    1.053414] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x600000fff 64bit]
[    1.053444] pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    1.053461] pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    1.053764] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.053987] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 43
[    1.054396] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 43
[    1.054658] pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.055186] bcm2708_fb soc:fb: FB found 1 display(s)
[    1.067376] bcm2708_fb soc:fb: Registered framebuffer for display 0, size 1920x1080
[    1.136254] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    1.138882] iproc-rng200 fe104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    1.139311] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3ec00000 mem_size:0x40000000(1024 MiB)
[    1.140144] gpiomem-bcm2835 fe200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0xfe200000
[    1.140499] cacheinfo: Unable to detect cache hierarchy for CPU 0
[    1.278859] loop: module loaded
[    1.281722] spi-bcm2835 fe204000.spi: could not get clk: -517
[    1.283707] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    1.284394] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: failed to get enet clock
[    1.284409] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: GENET 5.0 EPHY: 0x0000
[    1.284426] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: failed to get enet-wol clock
[    1.284440] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: failed to get enet-eee clock
[    1.284462] bcmgenet: Skipping UMAC reset
[    1.350801] unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: Broadcom UniMAC MDIO bus
[    1.351717] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    1.352010] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    1.352057] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.352092] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.352118] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.352173] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.352190] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.352251] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.352625] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.352653] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.353439] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: hcc params 0x002841eb hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000009000000890
[    1.354082] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.354100] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.354120] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    1.354456] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    1.354469] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.354481] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.354491] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-1083-raspi xhci-hcd
[    1.354501] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.355076] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.355162] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.356006] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    1.356019] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.356030] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.356040] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-1083-raspi xhci-hcd
[    1.356050] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.356628] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.356685] hub 2-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.357698] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    1.357971] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    1.357980] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    1.357987] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    1.357997] Module dwc_common_port init
[    1.358543] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.359018] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.362040] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    1.362289] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    1.362599] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.41.0-ioctl (2019-09-16) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    1.366459] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.366463] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.366731] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    1.366899] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.369070] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.369214] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.369838] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = (____ptrval____)
[    1.372184] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
[    1.372715] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.391996] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    1.392063] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.392168] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.392560] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.392590] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    1.394031] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: 06296dccb74d00d5449bbf6b3caaa893f9f33d41'
[    1.395256] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Live Patch Signing: 14df34d1a87cf37625abec039ef2bf521249b969'
[    1.396456] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Kernel Module Signing: 88f752e560a1e0737e31163a466ad7b70a850c19'
[    1.396460] blacklist: Loading compiled-in revocation X.509 certificates
[    1.396517] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing: 61482aa2830d0ab2ad5af10b7250da9033ddcef0'
[    1.396566] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2017): 242ade75ac4a15e50d50c84b0d45ff3eae707a03'
[    1.396628] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (ESM 2018): 365188c1d374d6b07c3c8f240f8ef722433d6a8b'
[    1.396673] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2019): c0746fd6c5da3ae827864651ad66ae47fe24b3e8'
[    1.396714] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2021 v1): a8d54bbb3825cfb94fa13c9f8a594a195c107b8d'
[    1.396754] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2021 v2): 4cf046892d6fd3c9a5b03f98d845f90851dc6a8c'
[    1.396809] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2021 v3): 100437bb6de6e469b581e61cd66bce3ef4ed53af'
[    1.396860] Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (Ubuntu Core 2019): c1d57b8f6b743f23ee41f4f7ee292f06eecadfb9'
[    1.397106] Key type ._fscrypt registered
[    1.397109] Key type .fscrypt registered
[    1.415177] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    1.428077] Key type big_key registered
[    1.446434] Key type encrypted registered
[    1.446447] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    1.446468] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    1.446494] ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha1
[    1.446511] ima: No architecture policies found
[    1.446545] evm: Initialising EVM extended attributes:
[    1.446549] evm: security.selinux
[    1.446552] evm: security.SMACK64
[    1.446555] evm: security.SMACK64EXEC
[    1.446558] evm: security.SMACK64TRANSMUTE
[    1.446561] evm: security.SMACK64MMAP
[    1.446564] evm: security.apparmor
[    1.446567] evm: security.ima
[    1.446570] evm: security.capability
[    1.446573] evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1
[    1.450818] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    1.450885] fe201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0xfe201000 (irq = 14, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    1.455772] fe215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x0 (irq = 16, base_baud = 62500000) is a 16550
[    1.456115] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
[    1.457886] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    1.457892] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: DMA channel allocated
[    1.505251] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    1.506774] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.508294] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.511026] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    1.512546] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.521080] mmc0: SDHCI controller on fe340000.emmc2 [fe340000.emmc2] using ADMA
[    1.522367] of_cfs_init
[    1.522440] of_cfs_init: OK
[    1.527726] Freeing unused kernel memory: 4096K
[    1.541793] Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found
[    1.541800] Run /init as init process
[    1.573575] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    1.610786] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.619578] mmc0: new ultra high speed DDR50 SDXC card at address 5048
[    1.620343] mmcblk0: mmc0:5048 SD64G 59.7 GiB
[    1.623560]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3 p4
[    4.542705] xor: using function: 32regs (6779.000 MB/sec)
[    4.544577] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[    4.708555] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-generic
[    5.012035] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    6.124389] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    6.137487] systemd[1]: Failed to find module 'autofs4'
[    6.181860] systemd[1]: systemd 245.4-4ubuntu3.20 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    6.182561] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm64.
[    6.261031] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <iotedgesystem>.
[    6.356197] systemd-rc-local-generator[381]: /etc/rc.local is not marked executable, skipping.
[    6.696591] random: lvmconfig: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
[    7.277054] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    7.279625] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[    7.279849] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    7.280995] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    7.281971] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    7.282272] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    7.282426] systemd[1]: Starting of Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point not supported.
[    7.282886] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[    7.282969] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    7.283048] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    7.283399] systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[    7.283842] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
[    7.284097] systemd[1]: Listening on multipathd control socket.
[    7.284476] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    7.284828] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[    7.285048] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    7.285706] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[    7.286082] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    7.286540] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    7.287069] systemd[1]: Listening on Network Service Netlink Socket.
[    7.287472] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    7.287802] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    7.291814] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[    7.296260] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    7.301556] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[    7.306189] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
[    7.312225] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    7.316992] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[    7.321760] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    7.326914] systemd[1]: Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
[    7.332321] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module chromeos_pstore...
[    7.337167] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
[    7.342067] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module efi_pstore...
[    7.353040] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module pstore_blk...
[    7.363055] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module pstore_zone...
[    7.372806] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module ramoops...
[    7.373075] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in OpenVSwitch configuration for cleanup being skipped.
[    7.375510] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
[    7.375806] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
[    7.383345] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    7.388930] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[    7.394245] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[    7.399496] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
[    7.406584] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    7.407387] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    7.408072] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[    7.408822] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
[    7.412308] systemd[1]: Finished Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    7.414818] systemd[1]: modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service: Succeeded.
[    7.416380] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module chromeos_pstore.
[    7.418437] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Succeeded.
[    7.419919] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
[    7.422289] systemd[1]: modprobe@efi_pstore.service: Succeeded.
[    7.423743] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module efi_pstore.
[    7.426293] systemd[1]: modprobe@pstore_blk.service: Succeeded.
[    7.427894] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module pstore_blk.
[    7.429931] systemd[1]: modprobe@pstore_zone.service: Succeeded.
[    7.431365] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module pstore_zone.
[    7.433306] systemd[1]: modprobe@ramoops.service: Succeeded.
[    7.434585] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module ramoops.
[    7.438867] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Modules.
[    7.442165] systemd[1]: Finished Uncomplicated firewall.
[    7.442201] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    7.448370] systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
```

I've tried multiple combinations of kernel module APT packages. Saw that my image uses 5.4.0-1083 but there still was 5.4.0-1069. Tried to remove 1069 ones, tried to install other 1083 packages that weren't installed, tried to remove 1083 and use only 1069. Many desperate tries. Even tried to mount the working partition on some folder, copy all the kernel modules to the current partition (/lib/modules/5.4.0-1083-raspi/*) but after reboot everything new things disappeared.

At least if I can get docker to work that would be great.

Latest thoughts I had is that maybe it has to do with initramfs. Maybe some configurations are missing in /boot folder (note that i'm using raspberry pi so some configs are in /boot/firmware, which is mounted, but not /boot entirely)